# Clean objects compiled in a different directory with make clean command

Tags: linux, makefile, compilation

My project has the following directory structure

```
root
    dirA
    dirB
```

The Makefile is in `dirB`, and this is where the make commands are executed from.
All files are included in the object list, therefore, when running `make` from `dirB`, the object files are generated in `dirA` and in `dirB`.
When running `make clean` from `dirB`, only the objects in `dirB` are cleaned, leaving the objects in `dirA` as is.

Looking for a suggestion to alter either the Makefile, or add some more info to the clean command (Which is not an explicit `rm`) in order to take `dirA` into account and clean the objects there as well.

The Makefile is something like the below

```
DIRA_PATH=../dirA/

obj-m += a.o
ena-objs := b.o \
    $(DIRA_PATH)/c.o \

ccflags-y := -I$(src)
ccflags-y += -I$(src)/$(DIRA_PATH)/

BUILD_KERNEL ?= $(shell uname -r)

all:
    $(MAKE) -C /lib/modules/$(BUILD_KERNEL)/build M=$(CURDIR) modules

clean:
    $(MAKE) -C /lib/modules/$(BUILD_KERNEL)/build M=$(CURDIR) clean
```

Comment: I would alter the makefile. I can't tell you exactly how, since you haven't shown it to us.

Comment: You're right, apologies, I updated the question

Answer (score 0):

This makefile is recursive; that is, it has recipes that invoke Make. It calls a makefile in another directory, which you haven't shown us, so all I can do is make an educated guess. Try adding a line to the `clean` recipe:

```
clean:
    $(MAKE) -C /lib/modules/$(BUILD_KERNEL)/build M=$(CURDIR) clean
    $(MAKE) -C /lib/modules/$(BUILD_KERNEL)/build M=$(CURDIR)/../libA clean
```

Comment: Thank you for replying, apologies for not noticing this earlier.
I don't have an option to add a Makefile in libA, so it actually doesn't trigger a makefile, but rather compiles the files directly `ccflags-y += -I$(src)/$(DIRA_PATH)/`

Comment: @just_a_user: I have read your comment several times, and I can't understand it. What does the `clean` recipe do?